# Почему именно пять? Что не так?

Tags: числительные, реклама

Кому-то попадался, а кому-то и успел надоесть рекламный ролик с таким текстом: «Не один. И не два. Вообще не пять. Не семь. И даже не девять. А целых 10 процентов». Визуальный ряд не даёт ответа на вопрос: что не так с гипотетической скидкой в 5%? А она не ниже многих других в этом перечне.

Comment: Я посмотрел эту рекламу, и мне кажется, что там какая-то привязка к видеоряду. Но какая — я не въехал.

Comment: А мне кажется, что это чисто оформительский прием, а никакого особого смысла числа не имеют.  Просто нужно было их разнообразно перечислить, заинтриговать, привлечь внимание к нарастающему постепенно ряду – где остановятся, на какой цифре?